# RegEx to Search in Multiline Text

Tags: python, regex, multiline

assume I have a text file like this: (Multiline) (Notice label1,label2,label3)

```
label1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
Lorem ipsum dolor-
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (dolor sit)
Hint Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent tellus
lkorem ipsum dolor.
Start Value : 0.25 [kg]
label2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amer, consecflsşl
the solor dolar
Start Value : 8000 [mg]
label3 Start Value : 0.3 [kg]
```

In here aside from lorem ipsum texts, I have label1, label2, label3 as strings in a list.

For every label, I need to get "Start Value : xxx [yy]" They can be positioned in a list or dictionary.

For example, for label1 in this text I need to get: "Start Value : 0.25 [kg]"

There may be lines between labels and their start value, or they may be side to side line in last line.

In my idea, I need to use RegEx to search string areas starting with - label name, and ends with a string where the string starts with "Start Value : " and ends with "]" How can I complete this task?

So far I tried re.findall(...) but could not understand.

Comment: How can we identify the line containing the label?

Comment: I have all label names in a list. Therefore, for example in a loop, I can search by a label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to first use `re.findall` to find all text blocks belonging to each label.  Then iterate that result and find the `Start Value` lines for each label.

```py
inp = """label1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
Lorem ipsum dolor-
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (dolor sit)
Hint Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Praesent tellus
lkorem ipsum dolor.
Start Value : 0.25 [kg]
label2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amer, consecflsşl
the solor dolar
Start Value : 8000 [mg]
label3 Start Value : 0.3 [kg]"""

labels = ["label1", "label2", "label3"]
regex = r'\b(?:' + r'|'.join(labels) + r')\b'
matches = re.findall(r'(?:^|(?<=\n))' + regex + r'.*?(?=' + regex + r'|$)', inp, flags=re.S)
output = [re.search(r'\bStart Value\s*:\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*\[\w+\]', x).group() for x in matches]
print(output)

# ['Start Value : 0.25 [kg]', 'Start Value : 8000 [mg]', 'Start Value : 0.3 [kg]']
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not post any code of how you wrote it so I will just post my solution.

use `^label\d(.|\n)+?Start Value : (.+?)(\[.+?\])` by enabling re.MULTILINE will works.

```py
import re

regex = r"^label\d(.|\n)+?Start Value : (.+?)(\[.+?\])"

test_str = ("label1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing \n"
    "Lorem ipsum dolor-\n"
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (dolor sit)\n"
    "Hint Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent tellus\n"
    "lkorem ipsum dolor.\n"
    "Start Value : 0.25 [kg]\n"
    "label2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amer, consecflsşl\n"
    "the solor dolar\n"
    "Start Value : 8000 [mg]\n"
    "label3 Start Value : 0.3 [kg]")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for m in matches:
    for g in m.groups()[1:]:
        print(g)
    print()
```

Comment: If you also use `re.DOTALL` flag, you can use `.+?` instead of `(.|\n)+?`.

Comment: One potential problem with this approach is that should a given label block _not_ have a `Start Value` line, the regex would match across labels to the next label having this text.